# How to color a Google Sheets tab in R with googlesheets4

Tags: r, googlesheets4

I am working the `googlesheets4` package in R and I'm wondering if there is a function that exists for changing the color of a tab?

For example, I am looking to make color a tab brown.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way in the native Sheets interface? What have you searched for in the API docs and teh package docs?

Comment: @IRTFM I'm sure there is but I'm developing with the `googlesheets4` package and would prefer to use that directly.

Comment: I’m just saying you should give more background and make more effort at investigating if you want help from a group of people who don’t use both platforms. Just an attempt at formative criticism.

Answer (score 3):

`googlesheets4` does not support setting tab color. However, the [Sheets v4 API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#SheetProperties.FIELDS.tab_color_style) does.

The function, `sheet_set_tab_color`, can be created like other functions in `googlesheets4` which update sheet properties.

```
library(googlesheets4)


sheet_set_tab_color <- function(ss, sheet = NULL, r, g, b) {
  ssid <- as_sheets_id(ss)
  sp <- list(
    sheetId = googlesheets4:::lookup_sheet(sheet, sheets_df = gs4_get(ssid)$sheets)$id,
    tabColorStyle = list(rgbColor = list(red = r, green = g, blue = b))
  )
  
  update_req <- list(
    properties = sp,
    fields = gargle::field_mask(sp)
  )
  
  req <- request_generate(
    "sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate",
    params = list(
      spreadsheetId = ssid,
      requests = list(updateSheetProperties = update_req)
    )
  )
  
  resp_raw <- request_make(req)
  gargle::response_process(resp_raw)
  
  invisible(ssid)
}
```

This sets the tab color as expected

```
ss <- sheet_write(iris)
sheet_set_tab_color(ss, sheet = NULL, r = 1.0, g = 0.3, b = 0.4)
```

[image: Colored tab]